# RxJS Observables - multiple subscribers getting reference to same object

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I've made an angular service to share state data across multiple components in my application.  In order to share, it has a BehaviorSubject that can be subscribed to

```
export class DesignerService {
  private selectedFieldBehavior: BehaviorSubject<FormField> = new BehaviorSubject(this.selectedField);

  getSelectedField(): Observable<FormField> {
    return this.selectedFieldBehavior.asObservable();
  }
}
```

Multiple components subscribe to this via the getSelectedField() method.  When I use `next()` to send a new object ( this.selectedFieldBehavior.next({ object })  ) , if any component subscribing to it modifies a property, all the subscribing components see that modification without notifying the service (like it's sending a reference instead of a copy), thus allowing the individual subscribers to modify each other's data

I've done a bit of work with angular/redux in the past, and I thought they promoted one-way dataflow and immutability.  Reducers were the only way to modify the state, and then changes were propogated downwards to the subscribing components.  What I currently have will allow child component to modify whatever they want.  I'm not super experienced with building large angular apps that require state management.  Am I mis-understanding how state management should work?

Comment: have you tried to clone the object? copy by value?

Comment: how/where would you do that?  in the service, or in each component that is subscribing?

Comment: Made some edits to the question to make it hopefully easier to understand what I'm asking

Comment: *like it's sending a reference instead of a copy*: well, that's exactly what it does. References to objects are passed in JavaScript. That's how it works. *I thought they promoted [...] immutability*: yes, and you chose not to use an immutable object, but a mutable one instead. emit an immutable object, and nobody will be able to mutate it.

Comment: @JBNizet is there a method/library you'd suggest for that?

Comment: Typecript allows defining fields as readonly. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#readonly-modifier

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change your method a bit to return a clone

```
getSelectedField(): Observable<FormField> {
  return this.selectedFieldBehavior.asObservable().map(obj=>Object.assign({},obj));
 }
```

Comment: Watch out, this creates a **shallow** clone.